# Find the first empty slot in Array list using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, graphics, inventory

I am trying to make an inventory for my game and I have two problem that i cant figure out how to fix. One of the problems is that the slots seem to be on the same position, I want to have a space of 25 pixles and the other problem is that the game only show one slot at the time instead of all of them.
Keep in mind that i'm not a good programmer.

Here is my code:

```
public void loadInventory(Graphics g){
    if(item != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < slot.length; i++){
            if (slot[i] == null) {
                slot[i] = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < slot.length; i++){
            if (slot[i] != null){               
                g.drawString(item.getName() + ": " + itemGroup.size(), 400, 100 + (i * 25));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here item is not provided to the method but a field :

```
public void loadInventory(Graphics g){
    if(item != null){
```

So, you override the item at each time that you invoke the method `loadInventory()`.
Change the method so that is accepts an array or better a List of `Item` :

```
public void loadInventory(Graphics g, List<Item> items){
```

And use this list to draw them :

```
for (int i = 0; i < slot.length; i++){
        if (slot[i] != null && items.get(i) != null){               
            g.drawString(items.get(i).getName() + ": " + itemGroup.size(), 400, 100 + (i * 25));      
        }
    }
}
```

And remove the `break` that terminates the loop.

Comment: If I remove all the breaks then all the slots are filled with the same item. And the if i pickup another item then all the slots are filled with that item.

Comment: Now I getting an error on the line where i am adding an items to the list.

Comment: Would it help if I post the whole Inventory Class?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xfswdiwnzrca781/AAC3luHj4m9UYUTj0dmfR3C9a?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Remove the break statements - they stop all execution of code and won't allow the rest of the logic to follow.

You don't need the extra for statement either.

```
public void loadInventory(Graphics g){
    for (int i = 0; i < slot.length; i++){
        if(item != null){
            if (slot[i] == null) {
                slot[i] = "";
            }
         }  if (slot[i] != null){               
                g.drawString(item.getName() + ": " + itemGroup.size(), 400, 100 + (i * 25));
            }
    }
```